# How to partition while installing Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: windows, xampp, alias

I have 320 GB hard disk.
I want to create like Windows partitions like `C` drive for OS install.
and `D`,`E` for store other files.

I try this already. but that is partitioned as like USB flash drives. 
This partitions only stored files.

But I tried to create alias for XAMPP projects from this folders. It shown forbidden errors.

So how to create partitions?

Answer (score 0):

I think English may not be your first language, so I am going to attempt to answer what I think is your question(s). I can only imagine what it would be like trying to ask a similar question in your language.

First off, formatting a linux installation like a windows drive is not necessarily the right way to go. Windows formatted things that way because it, well is windows and like to do things, backwards and sometimes badly.

The three general configurations that linux systems are configured are:

### Everything in "/"

Everything in is basically put in root except boot and swap. You actual disk will look something like...

/boot

/swap

/

### Everything in "/" except "home"

This is the same as above, except you put the "home" directory off in a separate partition. Some people think that this makes it a bit easier to totally blow away your OS base install and not have to backup/recover or do anything with your "home" if you do. Which it does in a way, but there can be some other things that come up as well. You drive will look like...
/boot

/swap

/

/home

### "/", "home", "/-other things"

In some configurations, typically server installations, where for instance the log directory is going to take up a lot of space or potentially eat up the file system, the "/var/log" directory might be put on its on partition. These are all custom configurations... So your drive might look like...

/boot

/swap

/

/home (optionally if you chose this)

/var/log

During installation when you come to the disk partitioning scheme if you want to set up anything other than the default partitioning scheme, then you will need to choose the custom or manual option and set the disk up yourself. If you don't know how to do this, there are a lot of guides online that can walk you through it.

If you are worried about some issue later like having your linux disk layout mirror a windows disk layout to use some samba shared configuration that a windows machine is going to access, don't. In the configuration of that you can make the windows client see essentially what you want it to see.